# Navigation with JSF and JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm creating a web application for mobile using JSF 2.2, Primefaces and JQuery Mobile. I'm using single pages and I have a problem navigating between them.

After a link is clicked, the JSF component h:commandButton of the new page doesn't work. I need to refresh the page manually.

```
<a href="message" class="ui-btn menu-item" data-transition="none">
   #{msgs["menu.message"]}
</a>
```

I can add the property data-ajax="false" to the link and it works, but then I lost the nice transition between pages that is something required in my project.

I guess that the problem is caused because JQuery Mobile load the new page with ajax replacing only the content of the data-role="page" element. And I think that the h:commandButton doesn't work because the jsf.js isn't reloaded. I know that I can detect that the new page is created with:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#container", function(){
...
});
```

How can I do nice transitions between pages and the jsf components of the new page working well? Is it possible and recommendable to reload the javascript files in the pagecreate?

I would like to have a solution without Primefaces. But it's also valid if there isn't any other possibility.

Comment: I am not sure why you think that reloading jsf.js will cause the commandButton to work.  What exactly is not working with it?  Do you get a Javascript error that it cannot find a function that would be in jsf.js?

Comment: I didn't check it before but the error that I receive in the console when I click the  h:commandButton is: Uncaught ReferenceError: mojarra is not defined onclick.

Comment: Finally I found the problem. The <h:outputScript library="javax.faces" name="jsf.js" /> need to be present in all the pages.